# Como usar um details-control dentro de outro details-control em uma DataTable?

Tags: jquery-datatables, laravel-5.8

Estou fazendo um dataTables para mostrar os detalhes de movimentação de cada lote que sai do estoque, a minha intenção com o segundo dataTables e dar um "explode" em cada item para exibir os números de serie respectivos, porem ele só referencia a tabela principal, nesse caso eu preciso referenciar a tabela que e criada dinamicamente pegando o id de cada produto e detalhando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script id="details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table class="table details-table testeTable" id="posts-@{{id}}">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th width="60%">Produto</th>
                <th width="30%">Quantidade</th>
                <th width="10%">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </script>
    <script id="details-template-sub" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table class="table details-table" id="sub-posts-@{{id}}">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="60%">Produto</th>
                <th width="30%">Numero de Serie</th>
                <th width="10%">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </script>

function handlerbutton(){
            $('.testeTable tbody').on('click', 'tbody button', function () {
                console.log('aqui');
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);
                var tableSubId ='sub-posts-' + row.data().id;

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(templateSub(row.data())).show();
                    initTableSub(tableSubId, row.data());
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                    tr.next().find('td').addClass('no-padding bg-gray');
                }
            });
        }

 function initTableSub(tableSubId, data) {
            $('#' + tableSubId).DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: data.urlSub,
                columns: [

                    { data: 'descricao', name: 'descricao' },
                    { data: 'numero_serie', name: 'numero_serie' , "defaultContent": ''},
                    { data: 'excluir', name: 'excluir', orderable: false, searchable: false }
                ]
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Resolvido]**

depois de alguns testes descobrir que na verdade eu estava referenciando a tabela errada, cada tabela e montada com uma query diferente, logo is IDs são diferentes! segue o código fonte abaixo.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**CSS**

precisei mexer no bootstrap do datatables e acrescentar um novo botão, pois o 'details-control' estava sendo sobrescrito

`td.sub-details-control {
    background: url('../images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 18px;
}
tr.shown td.sub-details-control {
    background: url('../images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}`

---

**BLADE - SCRIPT**
`<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Lista de Movimenta&ccedil;&otilde;es em Lote
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table id="users-table" class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Lote</th>
                                <th>Local Atual</th>
                                <th>Data da Movimenta&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                                <th>O.S.</th>
                                <th>Utilizador</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
`<script id="details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table class="table details-table" id="@{{id}}">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th width="10%">ID</th>
                <th width="50%">Produto</th>
                <th width="30%">Quantidade</th>
                <th width="10%">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </script>`

```
<script id="details-template-sub" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table class="table sub-details-table" id="sub-@{{id}}-@{{lote_id}}">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="60%">Produto</th>
            <th width="30%">Numero de Serie</th>
            <th width="10%">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#details-template").html());
    var templateSub = Handlebars.compile($("#details-template-sub").html());
    let subtable;
    let subdetalhe = [];
    var table = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "{{ asset('vendor/laraerp/template/datatables_portuguese-Brasil.json') }}"
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.lote') !!}',
        columns: [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "searchable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'local', name: 'local'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'DescricaoServico', name: 'DescricaoServico'},
            {data: 'nome', name: 'nome'},
            {data: 'editar', name: 'editar', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],
        order: [[2, 'desc']]
    });

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#users-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

        $('#excluiItem').html('')
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);
        var tableId =  row.data().id;
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(template(row.data())).show();
            initTable(tableId, row.data());
            tr.addClass('shown');
            tr.next().find('td').addClass('no-padding bg-gray');
        }
    });

    function initTable(tableId, data) {
        subtable=$('#'+tableId).DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: data.url,
            columns: [
                {
                    "className":      'sub-details-control',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "searchable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { data: 'id', name: 'id', visible: false },
                { data: 'descricao', name: 'descricao' },
                { data: 'quantidade', name: 'quantidade' },
                { data: 'excluir', name: 'excluir', orderable: false, searchable: false }
            ],
            "createdRow": function( row, data ) {
                if ( !data["controla_serie"]) {
                    $("td.sub-details-control", row).removeClass("sub-details-control");
                }
            }
        })
        $('#'+tableId).on('click', 'td.sub-details-control', function () {
        $('#excluiItem').html('')
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = subtable.row(tr);
        var tableId =  'sub-'+row.data().id;
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(templateSub(row.data())).show();
            initTableSub(tableId, row.data());
            tr.addClass('shown');
            tr.next().find('td').addClass('no-padding bg-gray');
        }
    });
    }
    function initTableSub(tableSubId,data ) {

        subdetalhe[data.id] = $('#sub-' + data.id+'-'+data.lote_id).DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            destroy: true,
            ajax: data.urlSub,
            columns: [
                {data: 'descricao', name: 'descricao'},
                {data: 'numero_serie', name: 'numero_serie'},
                {data: 'excluir', name: 'excluir', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]
        })

    }

</script>
```

---

**CONTROLLER**

seguem as funções com as querys caso alguém precise tirar alguma duvida sobre as rotas criadas

`public function anyData()
    {
     $lotes = Lote::query()
         ->join('historico_patrimonios', 'lotes.id', '=', 'historico_patrimonios.lote_id')
         ->join('ordens_servicos_internas', 'historico_patrimonios.ordemServico_id', '=', 'ordens_servicos_internas.id')
         ->join('local_armazenamentos', 'historico_patrimonios.local_destino_id', '=', 'local_armazenamentos.id')
         ->join('pessoas', 'lotes.pessoa_id', '=', 'pessoas.id')
         ->select('lotes.id', 'local_armazenamentos.local', 'lotes.created_at', 'ordens_servicos_internas.DescricaoServico', 'pessoas.nome')->distinct();`

```
    return DataTables::of($lotes)->addColumn('editar', function ($data) {
        $button = "<a href='".route('patrimonioLote.editaMovimentacao', $data->id)."' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Adicionar Produtos ao Lote'>
                        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Produto
                    </a>";
        return $button;
    })->addColumn('url', function ($data) {
        return url('patrimonio/details-lote/' . $data->id);
    })->editColumn('created_at', function ($user) {
            return $user->created_at->format('d/m/Y');
    })->rawColumns(['editar','url'])->make(true);

}

public function getDetailsLote($lote)
{
    $itens = MovimentacaoEstoque::query()
        ->join('produtos', 'movimentacao_estoques.produto_id', '=', 'produtos.id')
        ->select(['produtos.id', 'produtos.controla_serie', 'produtos.descricao', \DB::raw("'0' as patrimonio_id"), 'movimentacao_estoques.quantidade', 'movimentacao_estoques.lote_id'])->where('movimentacao_estoques.lote_id', $lote)->groupBy('produtos.descricao');

    return DataTables::of($itens)->addColumn('urlSub', function ($data) {
        return url('patrimonio/details-lote-sub/' . $data->id.'/'.$data->lote_id);
    })->addColumn('excluir', function ($data) {
        $valida = Produto::query()->select(["controla_serie"])->where('id', $data->id)->get();
        if(!$valida->first()->controla_serie == 1) {
            $btn = "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-id='" . $data->id . "' data-lote-id='" . $data->lote_id . "' data-patrimonio='" . $data->patrimonio_id . "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#excluirItemMovimentacao'>
                    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>
                </a>";
        }else{
            $btn = '';
        }
        return $btn;
    })->rawColumns([ 'urlSub', 'excluir'])->make(true);
}

public function getDetailsLoteSub($produto, $lote)
{

    $itensSub = MovimentacaoEstoque::query()
    ->join('produtos', 'movimentacao_estoques.produto_id', '=', 'produtos.id')
    ->join('historico_patrimonios', function ($join){
        $join->on('movimentacao_estoques.produto_id', '=', 'historico_patrimonios.produto_id');
        $join->on('movimentacao_estoques.lote_id', '=', 'historico_patrimonios.lote_id');
    })->join('patrimonios', 'patrimonios.id', '=', 'historico_patrimonios.patrimonio_id')
    ->join('numeros_series', function ($join){
        $join->on('patrimonios.numero_serie_id', '=', 'numeros_series.id');
        $join->on('patrimonios.produto_id', '=', 'numeros_series.produto_id');
    })->select(['produtos.id', 'produtos.descricao', 'numeros_series.numero_serie', 'movimentacao_estoques.lote_id', 'historico_patrimonios.patrimonio_id'])->where('movimentacao_estoques.produto_id', $produto)->where('movimentacao_estoques.lote_id', $lote);


    return DataTables::of($itensSub)->addColumn('excluir', function ($data) {
        $btn = "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-id='".$data->id."' data-lote-id='".$data->lote_id."' data-patrimonio='".$data->patrimonio_id."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#excluirItemMovimentacao'>
                    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>
                </a>";
        return $btn;
    })->rawColumns(['excluir'])->make(true);
}
```